# Nginx with Node.js as backend server always returns status code 200 instead of 404

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ejs

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy, with a Node.js Express server as the backend.

When trying to load a custom-made 404 page on Express, Nginx always returns a 200 status code, even though Express correctly sends back to Nginx a 404 status code.

What is the problem with the configuration?

I'm also using EJS as the template engine, however, I don't think it contributes to the problem. I am using PM2 as the process manager to run the server. I have tested without using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and everything in Express seems to work fine, i.e. Express correctly returns a 404 status code.

Here's my Express code:

```
const path = require('path')

const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const port = process.argv[2] || 3000

// Define paths for Express config
const publicDirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')

// Set EJS engine and views location
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', viewsPath)

// Set static files location
app.use(express.static(publicDirPath))

app.get('/testing404', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', {
        title: '404 error',
        content: 'This is a 404 error page.'
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started at port ' + port + '!')
})
```

Here's my relevant Nginx configuration:

```
upstream nthreads {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {

        root /var/www/[XXXXX]/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name [XXXXX] www.[XXXXX];

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nthreads;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

As explained, I expected a 404 status code to be returned from Nginx through the Node.js Express backend server, but I'm getting a 200 status code instead, what's the problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything was working correctly. I have forgotten to reload the server process, and it was running an old code without the 404 status code. Nginx does indeed correctly forward the 404 status code returned by the backend Node.js Express server.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is correctly returning 200 because you asked for a document that exists. You would only get a 404 if you requested a document that does not exist. Try doing that instead. (And whether such a document exists on some other server is completely irrelevant.)

when you’re pulling your 404 page at it’s genuine place, it will return a 200, because you’ve requested a page that does exist.

for Ngnix server you can Configure NGINX to point to that page for genuine 404 errors. Once that’s done, when you want to redirect your app in places just redirect them to a bogus page

Comment: Shouldn't Nginx forward the 404 status code returned by Node.js? For example, reaching the non-existent page "/pokdspoijopihspdkjl.html" should have returned the 404 status code as well, since that's exactly what happens in Node.js without using Nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: For a path and request that is not within itself, it returns a 404 error because it itself is a server. But for the node the request was correct and received the answer, then returns the result with the 200 code. You can process the entire error and the header and put it in the body of the result.

Comment: in node js or in Ngnix server?

Comment: Nevermind, turns out everything was working correctly. I have forgotten to restart the server process, and it was running an old code without a 404 status code. Nginx does indeed correctly forward the 404 status code returned by the server.